# Is there a way to change the color of vertices according to for example gender in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to make a weighted and directed social network. I would like to incorporate the genders of the individuals in this network, by making the males blue and the females pink. How do I do this?

My input data looks like this:

```
"name","id", "gender"
"ERIC",0, "Male"
"CHOICE",1, "Female"
"AMARILLO",2, "Male"
"YERMO",3, "Male"
"MOJITO",4, "Male"
"KESI",5, "Male"
"SUMBRIA",6, "Female"
"NOVIO",7, "Male"
"DIVA",8, "Female"
"CHICO",9, "Male"
"BELLE",10, "Female"
"PEPE",11, "Male"
"CARLOS",12, "Male"
"DIEGO",13, "Male"
```

```
"source","target","weight"
"ERIC","CHOICE",17
"ERIC","AMARILLO",3
"AMARILLO","CHOICE",19
"YERMO","CHOICE", 23
"YERMO","MOJITO",0
```

As codes I have used this:

```
install.packages("igraph")
library(igraph)

# Input data
edges <- read.csv(file.choose())
head(edges)

nodes <- read.csv(file.choose())
head(nodes)

library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed = T)
g

E(g)

# Make adjacency matrix
g[]

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(g)

# Adjust the size and color of the individuals and relationships
plot(g, layout=layout.circle, main="Circle",
     vertex.color = "orange",
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     vertex.size = 10,
     edge.color = "orange",
     edge.arrow.size= .4,
     edge.size = 20,
     main="Social network of Yellow-breasted capuchin")

betweenness(g, directed= TRUE)
degree (g, mode="all")


# Nodes aanpassen naar de betweenness
plot(g, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold(g),
     vertex.size=betweenness(g)*1.3,
     vertex.color = "orange",
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     edge.color = "orange",
     edge.arrow.size= .4,
     edge.size = 20)

g2 = simplify(g)

E(g2)$weight = sapply(E(g2), function(e) { 
  length(all_shortest_paths(g, from=ends(g2, e)[1], to=ends(g2, e)[2])$res) } )
plot(g2, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold(g2),
     vertex.size=30,
     vertex.color = "gold",
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     vertex.label.dist=0.5, 
     vertex.label.cex=0.8,
     vertex.label.degree=-pi/2,
     edge.width=E(g2)$weight*.8,
     edge.color = "orange",
     edge.arrow.size= 4,
     edge.size = 10)
```

I am quite new to R, so I am sorry about the mistakes. If you need additional information to solve this please say so. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! You can try this (you posted a lot of code, so I created a general one similar to your):

```
library(igraph)
# define the data for the graph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = TRUE, vertices =nodes)
# add the color: if Male, lightblue, else pink
V(g)$color <- ifelse(V(g)$gender == "Male", "lightblue", "pink")
```

Now you can plot the graph:

```
plot(g,
     vertex.color = V(g)$color,
     vertex.label.color = "black",
     vertex.size = 10,
     edge.color = "orange",
     edge.arrow.size= .4,
     edge.size = 0.4)
```

[image]

---

With data:

```
nodes <- structure(list(name = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 14L, 10L, 9L, 13L, 
11L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 12L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("AMARILLO", "BELLE", 
"CARLOS", "CHICO", "CHOICE", "DIEGO", "DIVA", "ERIC", "KESI", 
"MOJITO", "NOVIO", "PEPE", "SUMBRIA", "YERMO"), class = "factor"), 
    id = 0:13, gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))

edges <-structure(list(source = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AMARILLO", 
"ERIC", "YERMO"), class = "factor"), target = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("AMARILLO", "CHOICE", "MOJITO"), class = "factor"), 
    weight = c(17L, 3L, 19L, 23L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```